# how to delete an item from the database

Tags: c#, sqlite

The question is the following. I do not know how to properly organize the deletion of the receipt that I created. I didn't find any problems with the creation, but I haven't been able to delete it yet. I'm not very good at SQLite, as I haven't worked with it before, but I would really appreciate your help.

Page1.xaml.cs

```
public partial class Page1 : ContentPage
{
    public Page1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    protected override async void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();
        name_colec.ItemsSource = await App.Database_receipt.GetReceiptAsync();
    }

    async void new_reseipt(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string result = await DisplayPromptAsync("New receipt", "name");
        if (result.Length != 0)
        {
            await App.Database_receipt.CreateReceipt(new Database.Receipt
            {
                reseipt_name = result,
                reseipt_date = DateTime.Today.ToString("d"),
                reseipt_total = 1500
            });
            name_colec.ItemsSource = await App.Database_receipt.GetReceiptAsync();
        }

    }

     void delete_button(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

view_receipt_data.cs

```
public class Database_receipt
{
    readonly SQLiteAsyncConnection _database;
    public Database_receipt(string dbPath)
    {
        _database = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(dbPath);
        _database.CreateTableAsync<Receipt>().Wait();
    }
    public Task<List<Receipt>> GetReceiptAsync()
    {
        return _database.Table<Receipt>().ToListAsync();
    }
    public Task<int> CreateReceipt(Receipt receipt)
    {
        return _database.InsertAsync(receipt);
    }
}
```

upd:

```
public Task<int> RemoveReceipt(Receipt receipt)
{

    return _database.DeleteAsync(receipt);
}

 async void delete_button(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await App.Database_receipt.RemoveReceipt(receipt);
    name_colec.ItemsSource = await App.Database_receipt.GetReceiptAsync();

}
```

Comment: Check this samples: https://csharp.hotexamples.com/de/examples/SQLite/SQLiteAsyncConnection/DeleteAsync/php-sqliteasyncconnection-deleteasync-method-examples.html

Comment: @Fruchtzwerg okay , I realized that I had to write something like this in new Task : return _database.DeleteAsync(receipt); But I can't figure out how to write the action on the button correctly..

Comment: You should show what you've tried.

Comment: @Fruchtzwerg I added..but i don't know ehat to write in () where the line await App.Database_receipt.RemoveReceipt

Comment: @Fruchtzwerg so how do this correctly?

Comment: Sorry, but for me your question is totally unclear.